# Getting LatLong using NetWork Provider

Tags: android, google-maps, location, latitude-longitude

I am using below code to get LatLong, I am also using NetWorkProvider to get the LatLong:

The Below Code working fine :

```
        // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
        if (isGPSEnabled) {
            if (mLocation == null) {
                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                        5000,
                        5000, this);
                if (mLocationManager != null) {
                    mLocation = mLocationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    if (mLocation != null) {

                        //Called here...
                        onLocationChanged(mLocation);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

But, When I am using below code :

```
if (isNetworkEnabled) {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                    5000,
                    5000, MainActivity.this);

            if (mLocationManager != null) {
                mLocation = mLocationManager
                        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                if (mLocation != null) {
                    onLocationChanged(mLocation);
                }
            }
        }
```

I am getting mLocation `null`. What might be the reason ?

Answer (score 0):

Check permissions exists in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```